# visual studio 2022 package manager console get initializing powershell hosting message and program hanging

Tags: powershell, package, console, initializing

visual studio 2022

I am trying to open the package manager console to add some packages but I found  initializing PowerShell hosting message and program hanging and the screen not opened and I can not add any package

How can I resolve this problem?
[image: My problem]